# Classificação de dados de ataques a redes (ataque ou não ataque)

Tags: segurança, pandas, matplotlib

Estou usando o dataset:

```
https://www.unsw.adfa.edu.au/unsw-canberra-cyber/cybersecurity/ADFA-NB15-Datasets/
```

O objetivo é classificar uma amostra como ataque ou não ataque. Uma boa ideia seria usar a regressão logística?

Fiz o código abaixo pra fazer pairplots no dataset. O problema é que o dataset tem 49 colunas e eu gostaria de filtrar as colunas a usar no pairplot, tentei fazer um slice na varíavel UNSW11, como UNSW11[:,1:5], dentro do pairplot mas recebi erro: "builtins.TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'

Existe alguma forma de limitar o número de colunas a entrar no pairplot?

```
 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import seaborn as sns
    UNSW11 = pd.read_csv('/home/govinda/Desktop/UNSW-NB15_1_ed.csv')
    sns.pairplot(UNSW11,palette='bwr',hue = 'class') #usar hue!
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu fiz um teste com a base que você apontou e consegui selecionar as colunas do pairplot com o parâmetro vars :

`sns.pairplot(df,palette='bwr',hue="var45", vars=["var8", "var9","var41"])
plt.show()`

Considerando que var8,var9,var41 e var45 são respectivamente as colunas 8,9,41 e 45 do seu dataset

Este foi meu plot resultante

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Como você nomeou as colunas?